# Builder(android.app.activity) in Builder cannot be applied to anonymous (android.view.View.OnClickListener)

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

My error is

> ```
> Builder(android.app.activity) in Builder cannot be applied to anonymous (android.view.View.OnClickListener).
> ```

I'm trying to add custom alert dialog to be pop up on info button click, but unfortunately getting error above.

```
public class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    String TAG = "MyAdapter";
    Context context;
    List<ItemLoader> itemsList;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<ItemLoader> itemsList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.itemsList = itemsList;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        ((ViewPager)container).removeView((View)object);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.common_fragment,container,false);

        ImageView threeDots = view.findViewById(R.id.info_three_dots);
        ImageView firebase_image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image_firebase);
        TextView item_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        TextView item_bid_amount = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_bid_amount);

        Picasso.get().load(itemsList.get(position).getImage()).into(firebase_image);
        item_name.setText(itemsList.get(position).getName());
        item_bid_amount.setText(itemsList.get(position).getPrice());

        threeDots.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                      new FancyGifDialog.Builder(this)         
                        .setTitle("Granny eating chocolate dialog box")
                        .setMessage("This is a granny eating chocolate dialog box. This library is used to help you easily create fancy gify dialog.")
                        .setPositiveBtnText("Ok")
                        .setPositiveBtnBackground("#FF4081")
                        .setGifResource(R.drawable.gif1)   //Pass your Gif here
                        .isCancellable(true)
                        .OnPositiveClicked(new FancyGifDialogListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void OnClick() {
                                Toast.makeText(context,"Ok",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        })
                        .build();
            }
        });

        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }
}
```

I'm getting error in line `new FancyGifDialog.Builder(this)`.

Comment: what is the error you get? please provide full trace of logcat

Comment: Your question was marked as "requires editing" by a reviewer. Accordingly I improved the question formatting during a successing review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to change line from  `new FancyGifDialog.Builder(this)` to 
 `new FancyGifDialog.Builder((Activity)context)` as from the error

> `Builder(android.app.activity)` in Builder cannot be applied to
>   anonymous (android.view.View.OnClickListener)

it is clear that Builder constructor accepts Activity. So when in `onClick(View v)` method you write `new FancyGifDialog.Builder(this)`, you are trying to pass anonymous class of OnClickListener.
`new FancyGifDialog.Builder(this)` this line would have worked in the Activity Class.

Comment: @PraveenGupta kindly understand concept of passing parameters (actual and formal parameters), use of keyword `this`

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line of code :

```
new FancyGifDialog.Builder(this)
```

with :

```
new FancyGifDialog.Builder((Activity)context)
```

You already have context in adapter pass that simple.